# Can I read/write from/to the USB device that does not enumerate any device in /dev?

Tags: usb

I'm using a Texas Instruments MSP430F5529 Launchpad, but it is probably not important. This device upon connection enumerates 2 ACM devices: `/dev/ttyACM0` and `ttyACM1`. Once upgrading firmware something went wrong and these files are no longer created, that's why I cannot indicate this device to the firmware upgrade application.

However, the device can be seen in `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb | grep Texas
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0451:2046 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2046 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2047:03fe Texas Instruments 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2047:0203 Texas Instruments
```

Is there any way to access to `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2047:0203` as to a `/dev/ttyACM0` ?

Comment: Check `dmesg`'s output. Maybe the driver for the device is failing.

Comment: Interesting. What about `/sys` hierarchy, I suppose it is ok, given normal `lsusb` output? May be you could manually `mknod` a device file for your flash or write a `udev` rule for it? http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/sles9/adminguide-sles9/ch15.html

Answer (score 2):

For info I had the same problem recently (I came upon this query when looking for the answer).

To use mpsdebug without the /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyACM1 devices use

```
lsusb | grep Texas
```

to find the vid & pid - e.g

```
Bus 007 Device 040: ID 2047:0203 Texas Instruments 
Bus 007 Device 039: ID 2047:03fe Texas Instruments 
Bus 007 Device 038: ID 0451:2046 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB2046 Hub
```

and then use (doesn't seem to matter which one)

```
mspdebug -U 0451:2046 tilib
```

Though actually with tilib it looks like you can usually skip giving a device or USB VID:PID address at all and just do mpsdebug tilib

Answer (score 0):

I found that libusb allows to operate on VID:PID and in my case it was enough to use the mspdebug application that used the libusb.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mspdebug, but for the benefit of future visitors, could you perhaps expand on this answer to explain how it helped you solve the problem?